# Is there a way I can prevent IDMs from auto downloading pdfs on any user's PC that is using my Website

Tags: reactjs, pdf, idm

I'm developing a react app that is to be used by students to access reading materials, I'm using React-pdf-viewer to view documents and it's all working fine but for users with IDM extension on the pdf doesn't load in the viewer but instead it gets captured by IDM and prompt the user to download instead. I'm serving the pdf to the react-pdf-viewer as URL from my server. Is there a way I can prevent any IDM from auto downloading the pdfs. Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't mind them downloading it and  i have a download button set for that but with idm installed i have no control of who should download the document since the idm automatically captures it before it loads, Also i have a custom viewer setup with other features and it's in that viewer that i would like them to view the pdf from and only download it when they want AND have the rights to do it.